# parallel for loop and httpclient deadlocks and throws exception

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, dotnet-httpclient, parallel.foreach

I am confused about why my parallels.for loop is constantly blowing up on a httpclient call. 
  The code works for about 10-15 requests and then will hang for a long time and error out on with System.AggregateException 
  I have tried multiple different variations including webclient. 
  please consider the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Parallel.For(0, 250, i =>
        {

            var task = GetPages.CallHttp();
            task.Wait();
            var content = task.Result;
            TestObject obj = content.ToTestObject(); //take the string and find some values in it. 
            Console.WriteLine(obj.H1Tag);
        });
    }
}

public static class GetPages
{
    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient() {Timeout = new TimeSpan(0,5,0)};

   public static async Task<string> CallHttp()
    {

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("customAgent/1.0");
        string astr = await client.GetStringAsync("the url I am testing").ConfigureAwait(false);
        return astr;
    }
}

public static class StringExtensions
{
    private static readonly object objLock = new object();
    public static TestObject ToTestObject(this string content)
    {
        lock (objLock)
        {
            var obj = new TestObject();
// creates a bunch of properties inspecting the html string
            var result = new HtmlExtractions(content); 
            obj.PageTitle = result.PageTitle;
            obj.H1Tag = result.H1Tag;
           ...
            return obj;
        }
    }

}


public class HtmlExtractions
{

    internal HtmlDocument doc;

    public HtmlExtractions(string contentToRead)
    {
        doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(contentToRead);
    }

    public string PageTitle => doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("title").FirstOrDefault()?.InnerHtml.Replace("&amp;", "&").Trim();
...
}
```

the result is that is throws the following exception.

```
    System.AggregateException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=One or more errors occurred.
Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.<>c.<Main>b__0_0(Int32 i) in c:\users\username\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 27
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<ForWorker>b__1()
InnerException: 
   HResult=-2146233029
   Message=A task was canceled.
   InnerException: Id = 50, Status = Canceled, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"
```

******Update as per Todd's suggestion  // comments in the code. So frustrating. Even scaling to 5 requests results in hanging. ******

```
    static async void RunPagesAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("getting contents");
        var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(i => GetPages.CallHttp());
        var contents = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        Console.WriteLine("Got Contents..continuing");
        foreach (var content in contents)
        {
            TestObject obj = content.ToTestObject(); //take the string and find some values in it. 
            Console.WriteLine(obj.H1Tag);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("completed");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

      //Task.Run(() => RunPagesAsync()); //doesn't work. 
      //  RunPagesAsync(); //just hangs after what looks like 2 itterations

      //  var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(i => GetPages.CallHttp());
      //  var contents = await Task.WhenAll(tasks); //won't compile under synch Main dues to await 
      //  foreach (var content in contents)
      //  {
      //      TestObject obj = content.ToTestObject(); //take the string and find some values in it. 
      //      Console.WriteLine(obj.H1Tag);
      //  }

        var tasks1 = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(i => GetPages.CallHttp());
        var contents1 =  Task.WhenAll(tasks1); 
        contents1.Wait();
        foreach (var content in contents1.Result)
        {
            TestObject obj = content.ToTestObject(); //take the string and find some values in it. 
            Console.WriteLine(obj.H1Tag);
        }
```

Comment: Take a look at the `InnerExceptions` property of the `System.AggregateException`. Also, there is no need for the `lock` statement. There are no concurrent reads or writes as far as I can see

Comment: The inner exception is at the bottom of the post. I should have been more clear. A task was canceled. InnerException: Id = 50, Status = Canceled, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"

Comment: Regarding the lock I agree but at this point was shooting arrows in the dark.

Comment: @PeterBons any idea what might be the issue? I had tried the same code without the lock and had the same issue.

Comment: The line `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("customAgent/1.0");` is executed 250 times, in my test this generates an exception. You should refactor this so it is executed only once and not part of `CallHttp`. I suppose that collection is not thread-safe.

Comment: You're spanning 250 requests at the same time. Are you sure that you just don't get a http timeout (from your code it seems that it is a 5 minutes)

Answer (score 1):

Async tasks (which free threads) and `Parallel.For` (which forces the use of multiple threads) don't tend to mix well. `.Wait()` and `.Result` are both blocking calls and invite deadlocks when used with async tasks. Try re-writing your `Main` method using `Task.WhenAll` and avoiding the blocking calls:

```
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 250).Select(i => GetPages.CallHttp());
var contents = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
foreach (var content in contents)
{
    TestObject obj = content.ToTestObject(); //take the string and find some values in it. 
    Console.WriteLine(obj.H1Tag);
}
```

Comment: no real luck of any type. Updated code in question at bottom. Thank you for your suggestion though. It makes sense to create the collection first and then iterate.